# Concatenar resultados de comandos SH em uma linha

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Estou começando a aprender Shell Script e tenho com uma dúvida.
Estou criando um `.sh` para pegar o número de processos executando no SO e exportando essas informações em um arquivo `.csv`. O problema é que eu gostaria de salvar os resultados tudo em uma linha.

```
Exemplo atual:

    DATA
    PROC1
    PROC2
```

Esperado:

```
DATA PROC1 PROC2
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" >> /home/dsadm/LogProcessos/psResults.csv
ps -ef | grep osh | wc -l >> /home/dsadm/LogProcessos/psResults.csv
ps -ef | wc -l >> /home/dsadm/LogProcessos/psResults.csv
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem muitas maneiras, essa é uma:

```
echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` \; `ps -ef | grep osh | wc -l` \; `ps -ef | wc -l` >> log.csv
```

Tudo que vem entre *backticks* é executado pelo shell, como se o resultado tivesse sido digitado no lugar do comando.

Para separar as colunas, usei o escape `\` antes do `;` para não ser interpretado como divisor da linha de comando

Comment: Sua solução funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é usar `awk` com o comando `printf`, já que ele imprime o conteúdo de cada linha, mas sem adicionar a quebra de linha:

```
awk '{printf $0 " ";}' psResults.csv
```

Com isso todos as linhas do arquivo são unidas para ficar tudo em uma linha só, separados por espaço. Para fazer tudo no script, eu sugiro criar os dados em um arquivo temporário e só no final jogar a saída do `awk` no arquivo que você precisa:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Faz o que precisa no arquivo temporário
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" >> /tmp/results
ps -ef | grep osh | wc -l >> /tmp/results
ps -ef | wc -l >> /tmp/results

# awk joga tudo no arquivo final
awk '{printf $0 " ";}' /tmp/results >> /home/dsadm/LogProcessos/psResults.csv

# apaga o arquivo temporário
rm /tmp/results
```

Fiz assim porque se você fizer `awk ... arquivo > arquivo` ele pode sobrescrever o arquivo e perder tudo (e se fizer com `>>`, ele adiciona o conteúdo no final do arquivo). Usar arquivos diferentes é mais garantido.

---

Como se trata de um arquivo CSV, você pode trocar o comando para colocar vírgula (ou ponto-e-vírgula) em vez do espaço:

```
# vírgula
awk '{printf $0 ",";}' /tmp/results

# ponto-e-vírgula
awk '{printf $0 ";";}' /tmp/results
```

O problema é que assim fica uma vírgula no final (`DATA,PROC1,PROC2,`). Você pode eliminar isso fazendo um comando um pouco mais complexo, para verificar se está na última linha. Basta usar `wc -l` para contar as linhas do arquivo e coloque em uma variável, que será usada pelo `awk`:

```
# coloca vírgula entre os registros, exceto depois do último
awk -v last="$(wc -l < /tmp/results)" '{printf $0; if (NR != last) printf ","};' /tmp/results
```

Com isso, ele só coloca a vírgula se não for o último registro, resultando em `DATA,PROC1,PROC2`

---

Outra alternativa é usar `sed`:

```
sed -e :a  -e 'N;s/\n/ /;ta' psResults.csv
```

A opção `N` junta a linha atual com a próxima, e em seguida `s/\n/ /` substitui a quebra de linha por espaço. `ta` faz com ele faça um *loop* para o label `a`, que foi definido no começo (`:a`). Ou seja, ele repete esse processo de substituição até o fim do arquivo. No final, todas as linhas estão unidas em uma só, separadas por espaço.

Você pode trocar por vírgula, mas tem o mesmo problema de `awk` (coloca uma vírgula no final).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueCardoso Não esqueça de escolher uma das respostas e aceitá-la, caso ela tenha resolvido seu problema. Veja aqui como fazer: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052